# Delphi header translations for zebra barcode reader

Tags: delphi, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm looking for Delphi headers to use with the [zebra lib](http://zebra.sourceforge.net/)

I was lucky to find Delphi headers for Zbar at
ftp://ftp.lnssoftware.ca/Delphi/zbar.pas
which was great, but I would really like to find headers for zebra

Q1:
Can anyone point me to a download location?

Q2:
I would like to evaluate some barcode scanning solutions, so if anyone can recommend something that works in Delphi that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My employer has a 2D [DataMatrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_matrix_%28computer%29) barcode on every document and form that is sent out.   We then scan the results using an [OPEX Scanner](http://www.opex.com/prod_docscan.php?pid=9) The resulting TIFF images we send to 
the [SoftTek Barcode Reader](http://www.softeksoftware.co.uk/windows.html) which allows us to quickly identify the incoming form and account information.   Since it's an ActiveX control we were able to user it in Delphi easily.

We evaluated several options for reading barcodes but found that the SoftTek library allowed us to get the best read rates.   It's not a cheap library but it's has proven that it's value to our organization.

I just took a look at Zebra, the Version Control System had all the files deleted out of it on Sept 23, 2010.   I can't see where they may have (if they did) move the repository.
Browsing through the 51 revisions you can see the files that were available.   But it appears that the project owner either did not know how to use version control or was playing around.    Personally I would shy away from this library based on what I have seen in SVN.

Comment: I'm afraid that's way over budget. $3000 for a redistribution licence I don't want to spend. 
Got to agree with you on the state of the zebra lib though.

Comment: About the files being deleted: version control in the zbar project is now done with Mercurial, could what you have seen be part of the migration from SVN to Hg?

Answer (score 1):

The unit you link to looks pretty good, but it does 'late binding', to convert the unit to 'early binding' replace  all the functions and procedures in the implementation section to something of this syntax:

```
function xxx; external 'libzbar-0.dll' name 'xxx';
```

where xxx is the name of the function (and 'xxx' the parameter to GetAddressOf, but is in most cases the same)

Comment: Wow Stijn, great idea will do that.

Comment: Did it work? (funny thing: I might need to call zbar's dll also for a project I'm working on)